# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::make()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

Simply trying to use the example straight from the docs throws this error. I'm banging my head against the wall, I tried everything.

```
$collection = Collection::make([1, 2, 3]);
```

Despite the above being pulled right from the docs I get this:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1992:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::make()
```

Need to know how to make a custom collection from an array. I do not understand why this is difficult.

Comment: Do you have a Model named Collection?

Comment: Use `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` or the helper `collect()`

Answer (score 1):

To create collection you can simply use `collect` helper method this way:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3]);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$collection = new Collection([1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
// Notice the namespace here, probably you've used wrong namespace
$collection = \Illuminate\Support\Collection::make([1, 2, 3]);
```

Or using this helper function:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3]);
```